# How best to track a task start time and end time in a single table row?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, webforms

A person opens pages on a website to perform quality control tasks.
On one page, the activity of quality control starts when the person hits a start button. 
On another page, the activity starts when the page loads.

The activity of quality control can end once the person:

1. completes the task,
2. saves as incomplete, or
3. just closes the browser window.

The EndTime can occur anywhere from 10 seconds to 30 minutes after the 
start of the quality control task.

**The Issue:**
if you have a table with an **ActivityID**, a **StartTime**, and **EndTime** columns, 
what would be the best way of going about saving this information 
to the table, when the act of updating the existing record takes place outside of the stored proc that inserted the record? The StartTime has to be captured, which is straightforward enough, but then, however long after the task is completed, the End Time for the unique Activity has to be captured, and Activity EndTime has to be changed from NULL to the time of the "completion".

Some scenarios to consider:

- person A begins an Activity, then completes it. 10 seconds later,
  person B starts and finishes.
- person A begins an Activity, and then person B starts 10 seconds
  later,  and person A finishes 5 seconds ahead of person B. (I don
  believe any  kind of scope function would work here...
  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/ ?)

Would this route be acceptable...? Write a proc to call the Insert when the page loads. 
As part of the proc, insert the new activity and start time, and also 
return the value of the ActivityID (one method described here: 
[Get the ID of last inserted records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323528/get-the-id-of-last-inserted-records)). 
When the webpage hits an "end" event, then pass the ActivityID returned from 
the first proc, and call a proc that adds the End Time for the AcitivityID
that came from the first proc.

Comment: Your two-procedure tactic should work just fine, so long as you have the "user sesssion" remember the ActivityID. Your real problem kicks in when a session gets abandoned -- what happens if a deliberate "close activity" event never occurs? You might want a recurring check on open activities that closes all that are over 30 minutes old, and perhaps flag it as "abandoned" or "auto-closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  insert into [Table_2] ([valueStart]) values('start');
  select SCOPE_IDENTITY();

  int sqlIden = SQLcommand.execute();

  // perform task

  update [Table_2] set [valueFinish] = 'finish' where [id] = sqlIden.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the approach: the answer seems to assume a single proc for both updates? Part of my problem I don't think I can use a single proc to do this.