# getting last inserted ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL statement like

```
INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3)
```

Is there a way to get the list of all newly inserted rows?

Comment: I think you mean INSERT rather than INSET. Are you using a programming language, or are you doing this directly on the db? What variety of SQL? MSSQL? MySQL?

Comment: Thank for your comment It is INSERT statement for MSSQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323528/get-the-id-of-last-inserted-records

Answer (score 2):

Yes - if you're on SQL Server **2005** or newer - use the `OUTPUT` clause!

```
INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.col1
VALUES
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3)
```

This will output the `ID` and `col1` column for all new rows inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an `OUTPUT` clause in your `INSERT`?

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/